# xrandr detect when HDMI tv goes standby

Tags: display, hdmi, xrandr

I've got an LG tv connected through hdmi to my pc. Now when I run xrandr and the HDMI is connected and the tv is on i get the following:

HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97

When I unplug the HDMI cable te status goes from connected to disconnected (which is good).

However when I turn off my tv with the remote and keep the cable plugged the status stays on CONNECTED.

Any idea how you can detect that the tv is on standby/off?

The goal is to turn on/of services depending if the tv is on or off.

Kind regards and thx in advance
Jonathan

Comment: It may not be possible if the TV's standby mode keeps the HDMI "alive". And, using a digital connection to a modern FHD TV, why do you need xrandr for exactly?

Comment: Change TV from instant on to environmental friendly mode?